# python super calling child methods

Tags: python, oop, superclass

There are numerous questions on the usage of `super()` but none of them appears to answer my question.

When calling `super().__init__()` from a subclass, all method calls in the super-constructor are actually taken from the **subclass**. Consider the following class structure:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("initializing A")
        self.a()
    def a(self):
        print("A.a()")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # add stuff for B
        self.bnum=3 # required by B.a()        
    def a(self):
        print("B.a(), bnum=%i"%self.bnum)

b=B()
```

which fails with

```
initializing A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classmagic.py", line 17, in 
    b=B()
  File "classmagic.py", line 11, in __init__
    super().__init__()
  File "classmagic.py", line 5, in __init__
    self.a()
  File "classmagic.py", line 15, in a
    print("B.a(), bnum=%i"%self.bnum)
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'bnum'
```

Here I call the super constructor in `B()` to initialize some basic structure (some of which is executed as an own function `a()`). However, if I override the `a()` function as well, this implementation is used when calling `A`'s constructor which fails because `A` knows nothing about `B` and may use different internal variables.

This may or may not be intuitive, but what do I have to do when I want all methods in `A` only to have access to the functions implemented there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your code *has* to call specific private methods that cannot be overridden, use a name that starts with two underscores:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("initializing A")
        self.__a()
    def __a(self):
        print("A.a()")

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # add stuff for B
        self.bnum=3 # required by B.a()        
    def __a(self):
        print("B.__a(), bnum=%i"%self.bnum)
```

Python ["mangles"](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) such method names by adding in the class name (plus an underscore) to minimize the chances subclasses overwrite them with their own versions.

The [PEP 8 Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) has this to say about private name mangling:

> If your class is intended to be subclassed, and you have attributes
>   that you do not want subclasses to use, consider naming them with
>   double leading underscores and no trailing underscores. This invokes
>   Python's name mangling algorithm, where the name of the class is
>   mangled into the attribute name. This helps avoid attribute name
>   collisions should subclasses inadvertently contain attributes with the
>   same name.
>
> Note 1: Note that only the simple class name is used in the mangled
>   name, so if a subclass chooses both the same class name and attribute
>   name, you can still get name collisions.
>
> Note 2: Name mangling can make certain uses, such as debugging and
>   `__getattr__()`, less convenient. However the name mangling algorithm
>   is well documented and easy to perform manually.
>
> Note 3: Not everyone likes name mangling. Try to balance the need to
>   avoid accidental name clashes with potential use by advanced callers.

Comment: thanks for showing `__mangling`, I thought the leading underscores were just convention

Comment: @thias: if there are leading *and* trailing double underscores, no mangling takes place; methods with both leading and trailing underscores are 'magic' methods, hooks, and such, and are reserved for python itself mostly. Think `__init__`, `__getattr__` etc. Just to be explicit. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than calling `self.a()`, you'll need to use `A.a(self)`.  But this is not common to do for **all methods** on a particular class and *you should really re-evaluate whether `B` should inherit from `A`*.

Comment: that requires changing `A`'s implementation, which I wanted to avoid but thanks for pointing this out

Comment: @thias -- As far as I see it, you need to change the implementation of `A` no matter what (whether by name mangling as suggested by Martijn, or by specifying explicitly which method you're calling)

Comment: it's true. I do it now by calling the `__a` function in the constructor and implement an `a()` function that simply calls `__a` and can be overridden. That way, I have a consistent external interface but am still able to call `__a` from `A.__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this call:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
```

which is what happens when you call `super().__init__()`. This, in turn, calls `self.a()`, which is of course the function `a` of class `B` and not `A` because `self` is of class `B`. As Martijn stated, you can use dual-underscore names, or explicitly use the class name, but otherwise it is impossible to call an overridden method from a superclass.

Answer (score 0):

If we go through the instanciation steps of `B`:

- We call `super(B,self).__init__`, that is, `A.__init__`
- which calls `self.a()`, that is, `B.a()` in our case,
- which uses `self.bnum`

Except that `bnum` hasn't been defined yet... So, `AttributeError`.

For this particular case, it's just enough to define your `bnum` in `B.__init__` **before** calling `super(B,self).__init__`

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
       self.bnum=3
       super(B, self).__init__()
```

Before going the dark, dark path of name mangling, you may want to just take the time to organize the code of your subclass: should it be performed *before* the parent's, to initialize some special variables, or *after* the parent's, to replace some defaults ?

Comment: I can see that. My real problem is a little more involved, though (the implementation in the subclass uses a module that is not imported in the superclass namespace).

Comment: I think he doesn't want `B.a` to get called at all during the super call, so while declaring `bnum` before calling super doesn't throw an `AttributeError` anymore it is not actually a solution for his problem.

Comment: Ah. So, is `super(B,self).__init__` needed at all ?