# Connecting three classes from methods inside of them in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I am using `PyQt` to create an application with  `matplotlib` and I am trying to connect a method from one class with another method from another class.

Class A is a `QMainWindow` that instantiate `class B`, which is a `matplotlib` figure. So, when I  call method `a` from `class A` (connected to a `QPushButton` ), it calls `class C` to do something, and then it has to connect to `method b` in `class B` to do something else.

I read a lot of coding and I found this for example:

[python super calling child methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478186/python-super-calling-child-methods?rq=1)

which I tried to do, but it did not work.

This is the code I have:

```
class A(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()
    #A lot of stuff in here

    #I instantiate class B
    self.call_B = B()

  def a(self):
    print "Hello"
    self.open_C = C(self)

class B(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    #A lot of stuff in here

  def b(self):
    print "How are you?"

class C(B):
  def __init__(self):
    super(C, self).__init__()
    #A lot of stuff in here

    self.connect_to_b()      

  def connect_to_b(self):
    #From here is where I need to call method b() from class B
```

As you can see above, I need to connect method `connect_to_b` from `class C` to method `b` in `class B`.

How can I accomplish this?. Hope you can help me.

Comment: if `C` is of type `B`, it has access to `b`. just call `b` with `b()`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried that, but it does not worked. Maybe i am missing something. I get this error while doing this: `global name 'b' is not defined`

Comment: use `self.b()` because `b` is in your class

Comment: also, why do you pass in the class `A` to `C` when it doesn't accept any parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C` inherits from `B` so `connect_to_b` has access to `b`.

```
def connect_to_b(self):

    self.b()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that the problem with doing `self.b()` is that `B` is instantiated again, and it does not "do the job" in the `B` I instantiated in `A`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Is there another way to do this? `class C` can be modified, but it mus call that method in `B`

Comment: `B` is not instantiated again. `C` is of type `B`, so you have access to `b`. you're not instantiating it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had something wrong in my code. You were right. Thnak you a lot for all your help.